# Consul and registrator add port to service name

Tags: nginx, consul

I simply run a `consul` and the `registrator` container on the same machine using docker with `docker-compose`. In the same file an nginx service is started. However, the nginx is registered in consul with name `nginx-80`. I would like to have just `nginx` as the name. Any ideas?

Btw: Just replace nginx with any arbitrary service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stated with this issue, this happens when the docker EXPOSEs more than one port. Even though you publish only one.

https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/issues/437

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the following link:

- [Service-Name](https://gliderlabs.com/registrator/latest/user/services/#service-name)

I use it with docker-compose and have a service with two ports. I configured the service port with:

```
labels:
    SERVICE_PORT_NAME: servicename
```

Thank you @Taron I followed his link above and got the solution following a couple of links ...

[consul](/questions/tagged/consul)